# Issue with displaying Google Charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

This is my first day of exploring google charts, but it is not displaying the line chart. It is infact not showing anything.

**Here is my code:**

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    <%@ include file="demoGraph.css"%>
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {
      'packages': ['line']
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('number', 'Months');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Enrolled');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Inactive');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Guest');

      data.addRows([
        [Jan, 700, 1200, 800],
        [Feb, 1000, 275, 1800],
        [Mar, 1250, 220, 1500],
        [Apr, 1100, 400, 600],
        [May, 1900, 250, 1200],
        [Jun, 2000, 360, 1000],
        [Jul, 1500, 500, 1000],
        [Aug, 1300, 250, 1000],
        [Sep, 1700, 500, 1000],
        [Oct, 1200, 150, 525],
        [Nov, 1000, 250, 625],
        [Dec, 1920, 280, 700]
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'Demo Graph',
        curveType: 'function',
        legend: {
          position: 'bottom'
        }
      };

      var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="linechart_material" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

But on the web page its not displaying anything. Well according to them it should show graph, but its not. Could someone point what I'am missing ?

Comment: Do you get any error in the console?

Comment: its showing jan is not defined

Comment: your var "Jan", "Feb" ... are not defined ;-), quote them if they are supposed to be strings

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/56jekrec/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example.

1. In your code the months(Jan, Feb, ..) needs to be enclosed in `"`, else it will be treated as a `variable` which was not defined and error will be thrown.
2. Datatype for the column(month) should be `string`. Change `data.addColumn('number', 'Months');` to `data.addColumn('string', 'Months');`

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    <%@ include file="demoGraph.css"%>
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {
      'packages': ['line']
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Months');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Enrolled');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Inactive');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Guest');

      data.addRows([
        ["Jan", 700, 1200, 800],
        ["Feb", 1000, 275, 1800],
        ["Mar", 1250, 220, 1500],
        ["Apr", 1100, 400, 600],
        ["May", 1900, 250, 1200],
        ["Jun", 2000, 360, 1000],
        ["Jul", 1500, 500, 1000],
        ["Aug", 1300, 250, 1000],
        ["Sep", 1700, 500, 1000],
        ["Oct", 1200, 150, 525],
        ["Nov", 1000, 250, 625],
        ["Dec", 1920, 280, 700]
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'Demo Graph',
        curveType: 'function',
        legend: {
          position: 'bottom'
        }
      };

      var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="linechart_material" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Pugazh...i havn't try yet but by the looks of it it will works...thanks man you're my hero for today...happy coding

Comment: @AnkitRauthan : Welcome to Stack Overflow. Happy to help!

Comment: @ Pugazh can you help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38525879/issue-with-overlapping-in-bar-charts-in-google-charts

Comment: @AnkitRauthan : Yeah Sure!

Answer (score 0):

include the query if needed

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and change `data.addColumn('number', 'Months');` to `data.addColumn('string', 'Months');`

also change

```
data.addRows([
                    [Jan,  700, 1200, 800],
                    [Feb,  1000, 275, 1800],
                    [Mar,  1250, 220, 1500],
                    [Apr,  1100, 400, 600],
                    [May,  1900, 250, 1200],
                    [Jun,   2000, 360,  1000],
                    [Jul,   1500, 500,  1000],
                    [Aug,  1300, 250, 1000],
                    [Sep,  1700, 500, 1000],
                    [Oct, 1200, 150, 525],
                    [Nov,  1000,  250,  625],
                    [Dec,  1920,  280,  700]
                ]);
```

To

```
data.addRows([
                    ["Jan",  700, 1200, 800],
                    ["Feb",  1000, 275, 1800],
                    ["Mar",  1250, 220, 1500],
                    ["Apr",  1100, 400, 600],
                    ["May",  1900, 250, 1200],
                    ["Jun",   2000, 360,  1000],
                    ["Jul",   1500, 500,  1000],
                    ["Aug",  1300, 250, 1000],
                    ["Sep",  1700, 500, 1000],
                    ["Oct", 1200, 150, 525],
                    ["Nov",  1000,  250,  625],
                    ["Dec",  1920,  280,  700]
                ]);
```

here is the HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            <%@ include file="demoGraph.css"%>
        </style>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line']});
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

            function drawChart() 
            {

                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                data.addColumn('string', 'Months');
                data.addColumn('number', 'Enrolled');
                data.addColumn('number', 'Inactive');
                data.addColumn('number', 'Guest');

                data.addRows([
                    ["Jan",  700, 1200, 800],
                    ["Feb",  1000, 275, 1800],
                    ["Mar",  1250, 220, 1500],
                    ["Apr",  1100, 400, 600],
                    ["May",  1900, 250, 1200],
                    ["Jun",   2000, 360,  1000],
                    ["Jul",   1500, 500,  1000],
                    ["Aug",  1300, 250, 1000],
                    ["Sep",  1700, 500, 1000],
                    ["Oct", 1200, 150, 525],
                    ["Nov",  1000,  250,  625],
                    ["Dec",  1920,  280,  700]
                ]);

                var options = {
                    title: 'Demo Graph',
                    curveType: 'function',
                    legend: { position: 'bottom' }
                };

                var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));

                chart.draw(data, options);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="linechart_material" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>                    
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In you example you did not defined the your month variables. Since you defined your first row as number `data.addColumn('number', 'Months');` they need to be in a number format.

For Example: https://jsfiddle.net/56jekrec/1/